# AppWarp multiplayer with one host

Tags: cocos2d-x, multiplayer, game-development, appwarp

I had a question with using AppWarp that I was hoping someone could help me with.
Is it possible to have one host of a game that both users in a AppWarp room can view and send messages too in realtime? Rather then having each user have their own hosted game while sending messages to each other and altering their gameplay through  those sent and received messages.
The only reason I ask is because there are random factors in my game and if you add in latency from sending messages, both users don't see the same gameplay... I hope that makes sense. If this can't be done through AppWarp can someone recommend any alternatives? Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on the requirement you have? Is host a 3rd player in the game or it will be a bot user which will be interacting to other players as per AI written for him?

Comment: I need a server to host the game and have the devices to act as clients sending messages to the server/host. This way the gameplay is the same for every client

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the requirement correctly then you want to make a game where two or more clients should communicate with each other using AppWarp as a server. If that is the case then this is what AppWarp does. AppWarp is a server side product to which the clients can connect to communicate with each other. AppWarp has two flavours called [AppWarp Cloud](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/realtime-multiplayer-game-engine-overview/) and [AppWarpS2](http://appwarps2.shephertz.com/) which are explained in this [blog](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/04/26/when-to-use-multiplayer-cloud-and-on-premise-solution/).

You can go ahead and check out the tutorials and samples of AppWarp and if you face any problem you can write on its [forum](http://forum.shephertz.com/) to get it sorted quickly.

Comment: The game needs to run on the server, not on the devices. Maybe appwarpS2 can help me with this but I don't think AppWarp Cloud. I don't want peer to peer communication.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this case, you should go for AppWarpS2 as it allows you to customise the server side code as per the game requirement.

Comment: Yeah I figured out that is what I need. I rather not have to reprogram the game in Java though which is required by AppWarp, while my game is built with c++, oh well.